# How to check which QListWidget has selected item

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

i'm trying to do an application just drawing couple shapes and then if selected from one of three QWidgetLists and clicked a button, the selected shape would turn red. Drawing etc. isn't a problem, but i can't find out how can i check which list is active and has selected item. Current code looks like this:

```
    QPixmap pixmap(ui->display_field->width(),ui->display_field->height());
    pixmap.fill("transparent");
    int chosen_one;

    if(ui->radio_circle->isChecked()){
        if(circles_list.count() > 0){
            chosen_one = ui->circles_list_wgt->currentItem()->text().toInt();
            circles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::red);
            for(int i=0; i<circles_list.count(); i++) circles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
            circles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::black);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<rectangles_list.count(); i++) rectangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
        for(int i=0; i<triangles_list.count(); i++) triangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
    }

    if(ui->radio_rect->isChecked()){
        if(rectangles_list.count() > 0){
            chosen_one = ui->rectangles_list_wgt->currentItem()->text().toInt();
            rectangles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::red);
            for(int i=0; i<rectangles_list.count(); i++) rectangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
            rectangles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::black);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<circles_list.count(); i++) circles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
        for(int i=0; i<triangles_list.count(); i++) triangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
    }

    if(ui->radio_tri->isChecked()){
        if(triangles_list.count() > 0){
            chosen_one = ui->triangles_list_wgt->currentItem()->text().toInt();
            triangles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::red);
            for(int i=0; i<triangles_list.count(); i++) triangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
            triangles_list[chosen_one].setColor(Qt::black);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<circles_list.count(); i++) circles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
        for(int i=0; i<rectangles_list.count(); i++) rectangles_list[i].draw(&pixmap);
    }

    ui->display_field->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

The original app had a bit different method of working, depending on radiobuttons as it is right now. I want it to be item selection dependent only.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your solution:

1. You actually have *three* selections: Every `QListWidget` has its own selection, thus has its own *current* item.
2. You should do the drawing in a `paintEvent`.

I'd suggest the following:

- Subclass a `QWidget` that maintains the lists of items you want to draw.
- Implement the widget's `QWidget::paintEvent` method. This method is automatically called by Qt when then widget needs to be drawn on the screen. You can manually request this by calling `QWidget::update`, e.g. when your shape selection has changed.
- Maybe you even want to factor out the drawing into separate classes, like a `Rectangle`, a `Circle` and a `Triangle` class.

Then create your form including the three `QListWidget`. Create a single slot and connect the lists' `QListWidget::currentRowChanged` signals altogether to this single slot. It will hence be called whenever you pick another shape in any of the lists. Inside the slot, you can distinguish using the `sender()` routine from which of the lists the user picked a shape. Update your drawing widget accordingly, call `update` and you're done.